# Adding http request header to a a href link

Tags: html, http

I have a simple `href` link from some `html`

```
<a href="www.google.com">Apparently you can find things here</a>
```

But I want to add a http request header to the request?

Is this possible.

Comment: with only plain html? don't think so...

Comment: what headers you want to add?

Comment: @Ejay custom headers.  Trying to send some information over HTTP. Debating whether it makes more sense to add this to URL or as a header.

Answer (score 59):

There is no way for a page to specify HTTP request headers other than for requests made using XMLHttpRequest and fetch.

Answer (score 4):

Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

I don't believe it's possible to specify a request header via a link.  You can send GET parameters to the target site with the following notation:

```
www.google.com?q=searchterm
```

The first GET parameter is separated from the URL by a question mark (?) after that each additional parameter should be separated with an ampersand (&) like so:

```
www.google.com?q=searchterm&otherparam=value&otherotherparam=value
```