# Managing user permission in express-js by express-jwt

Tags: express, jwt, express-jwt

I'm building express web app in which I want to manage user permission to certain page based on JWT . For that I'm using express-jwt middleware to add token to the request url before the request is handled by server. In client side(pug) I'm requesting the page by 'href'.

```
a(href='/reqpage')
```

router to the controller :

```
const auth = jwt({
secret:process.env.JWT_SECRET,
algorithms:['sha512'],
userProperty : 'payload'
   })

router.route('/reqpage').get(auth, ctrlMain.reqpage);
```

Here how can I add token to the request header in client side, so that the middleware attach it to the request to controller.

Comment: If you mean adding the jwt token to the header for the request made by the client, you can't do that using just an <a> tag with "href", see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835783/adding-http-request-header-to-a-a-href-link). You should make an "onclick" attribute which runs a function that leads to an XMLHttpRequest, where you can then attach the token to the header.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Now I switched to cookies.